# Grails view URL Mapping

Tags: grails, url-mapping

I'm kind of new to grails and I'm trying to just map a basic URL request to a view.

So, say I have a view, /x/index.gsp and I want the user to be able to go to it.  There will also be /y/index.gsp, /z/index.gsp, etc.

I defined it like so:

```
"/$customer/index"          { view = {params.customer+"/index"} }
```

This seems to throw an exception though.  I also have :

```
"/$customer/$controller/$action?/$id?" { }
```

which does work and I don't want to have to create a controller that doesn't really do anything but handle the index call and show it.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the first mapping fails is because it can't figure out what controller to route the request to.

To fix it, you need to define what controller you want the top mapping to route to. This is how I did this in a recent project of mine:

```
"/uploaders/$id" {                                          
    controller: "uploader"                                  
}
```

---

[To map to just a view](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#mappingToViews):

```
"/$customer/index"(view: "/${params.customer}/index")
```

Comment: But I don't want to have to define a controller.  Why should I define a controller that does nothing but forward to a view?  Also, I won't know what the first part of the / is (in your case, /uploaders) as it will vary based on who the person logged in as

Comment: I Updated my answer to reflect what you are actually after.

Comment: Throws the error: No such property: customer for class: java.lang.String

Comment: `params` may not be available to the routing engine. Try using just `$customer`

Comment: @user965697: _"Why should I define a controller that does nothing but forward to a view?"_ Because Grails is MVC (Model View Controller)?